# Is there support for multiple oauth2 authentication login providers in SwaggerUI?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-ui

I can get multiple login options to appear in SwaggerUI with code similar to

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Google", new OAuth2Scheme
        {
            Description = "Google",
            Type = "oauth2",
            Flow = "implicit",
            TokenUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
            AuthorizationUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
        });

        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Microsoft", new OAuth2Scheme
        {
            Description = "Microsoft",
            Type = "oauth2",
            Flow = "implicit",
            TokenUrl = "blah",
            AuthorizationUrl = "blah"
        });

        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
        {
            Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
            In = "header",
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = "apiKey"
        });

        c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
```

and something similar to

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.OAuthClientId(this.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"]);
        c.OAuthClientSecret(this.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]);
        c.OAuthAppName("blah");
        c.OAuthScopeSeparator(string.Empty);
        c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new { audience = this.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"], scope = "openid profile email" });
        c.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    });
```

If I have just one oauth provider configured it works fine. The problem is that both the Google and Microsoft login options will use the default ClientId and ClientSecret etc. declared in the UseSwaggerUI method.

Is there a way of supporting multiple login providers and their associated configuration in Swagger UI?

Comment: Good question, certainly seems like the API does not allow it.. Maybe if you could add multiple Swagger UIs?

Comment: This is currently not supported in Swagger UI - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4690.

Comment: Thanks @Helen. I had searched alot before posting this thread but didn't find that issue. Might have to roll my own authentication for Swagger UI :(